# Transposing the column in SQL server and removing unwanted columns?

Tags: sql-server, transpose

I have a  table like this:

```
Dimension Code      Dimension Value Code    Entry No_
BUSINESSSEGMENTS       153                     1
TERMINAL               41150                   1
```

I want to transpose it, for that I am using this query:

```
select  *
from realTable
unpivot (value for DimValCode in ([Dimension Value Code])) up
pivot (max(value) for [Dimension Code] in (BUSINESSSEGMENTS,TERMINAL)) p
```

and it’s working fine and giving output like this:

```
Entry No_     DimValCode                   BUSINESSSEGMENTS     TERMINAL
   1          Dimension Value Code              153              41150
```

But I need this:(don't need DimValCode column)

```
Entry No_       BUSINESSSEGMENTS    TERMINAL
  1                  153             41150
```

What I need to modify in this query ?

Thanks.

Comment: Specify columns instead of `*`.

Comment: It gives error - Invalid column names. I guess it's a must to use * instead of column names while using pivot and unpivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT [Entry No_]
    ,[BUSINESSSEGMENTS]
    ,[TERMINAL]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM realTable
    unpivot(value FOR DimValCode IN ([Dimension Value Code])) up
    pivot(max(value) FOR [Dimension Code] IN (
                BUSINESSSEGMENTS
                ,TERMINAL
                )) p
    ) T
```